# How to modify this script to add date instead of date and time to the picture?

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick

I have come across this useful program to add date and time to photos. How can I modify the bat file so that it only adds date but not date time?

e.g. 2017:12:10 instead of 2017:12:10 10:10:02

```
@echo off & cls
rem enable variables referencing themselves inside loops
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem optional settings
set fontcolor=#FFD800
set fontoutlinecolor=#000000
set fontstyle="Arial-Bold"

rem create a new folder where the stamped images will be placed
mkdir stamped

rem loop through all jpg png jpeg and gif files in the current folder
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /A:-D /T:C "%cd%\*.jpg" "%cd%\*.png" "%cd%\*.jpeg" "%cd%\*.gif"') do (
    rem retrieve image date and time
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "tokens=1-2" %%i in ('identify.exe -ping -format "%%w %%h" "%cd%\%%a"') do set W=%%i& set H=%%j

    rem retrieve image timestamp to perform size and distance calculations on
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=" %%k in ('identify -format "%%[EXIF:DateTimeOriginal]" "%cd%\%%a"') do set timestamp=%%k

    rem set timestamp to no timestamp if there is no timestamp
    if "!timestamp!" == "" (
        set timestamp=No timestamp
    )

    rem print some information about the process
    echo %%a is !W! x !H! stamp !timestamp! ...

    rem set timestamp size to a fourth of the screen width
    set /A timestampsize = !W! / 3

    rem set timestamp offset distance from side of the screen
    set /A timestampoffset = !W! / 20

    rem set timestamp outline relative size
    set /A outlinewidth = !W! / 600

    rem echo !timestampsize! !timestampoffset!

    rem create a custom image with the timestamp with transparent background and combine it with the image
    convert.exe ^
    -verbose ^
    -background none^
    -stroke !fontoutlinecolor! ^
    -strokewidth !outlinewidth! ^
    -font !fontstyle! ^
    -fill !fontcolor! ^
    -size !timestampsize!x ^
    -gravity center label:"!timestamp!" "%cd%\%%a" +swap ^
    -gravity southeast ^
    -geometry +!timestampoffset!+!timestampoffset! ^
    -stroke !fontoutlinecolor! ^
    -strokewidth !outlinewidth! ^
    -composite "%cd%\stamped\%%a"

    endlocal
    endlocal
    echo.
)
endlocal
echo Complete!
pause
```

The original file place: 
https://nirklars.wordpress.com/2015/04/25/add-scaled-timestamps-to-photos/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get just the date from the EXIF time stamp by editing this line...

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=" %%k in ('identify -format "%%[EXIF:DateTimeOriginal]" "%cd%\%%a"') do set timestamp=%%k
```

Change that line to this...

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%k in ('identify -format "%%[EXIF:DateTimeOriginal]" "%cd%\%%a"') do set timestamp=%%k
```

That way you're using a space as a delimiter with "delims= " instead of "delims=". Then your variable "%k" only reads the output of the "identify" command up to the first space, which is just the date part. Then it sets your "%timestamp%" variable to that value and continues as before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak that awful Windows BATCH language monstrosity, but I suspect you need to change the line:

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=" %%k in ('identify -format "%%[EXIF:DateTimeOriginal]" "%cd%\%%a"') do set timestamp=%%k
```

to only take the first token, instead of the first two:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%k in ('identify -format "%%[EXIF:DateTimeOriginal]" "%cd%\%%a"') do set timestamp=%%k
```

If that doesn't work, and anybody who doesn't understand **ImageMagick** but does understand Windows BATCH, the following command:

```
identify -format "%%[EXIF:DateTimeOriginal]" someImage.jpg
```

produces this:

```
2013:03:09 08:59:50
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work, since the EXIF tag ins one single string that holds both date and time, and there is no other tag with only the day. So the solution is to parse/cut the output, which is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: @xenoid I understood that `FOR /F TOKENS=...` does exactly that - it splits the lines into individual items for assigning to successive variables, i.e. `%k` in this case.... https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html